# How to get samba4 installed. Having compiling errors

Tags: samba

I have Ubuntu 12.04 server installed.  I followed the install instructions for samba (Samba AD DC HOWTO) copied from [sambaWiki website](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO).  I only got to step 2 which is Compile Samba and received an error.  I have the c compiler loaded and it working.  I am getting errors that there are several files not copied to my server.  Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Glynn

Comment: What are the errors ? could you include them in your question

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that Ubuntu provides user-friendly [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/) for each version that has been released and and is currently supported. In the server guide, which is part of the official documentation, you can find a chapter for Windows Networking which contains a section on [**how to set up a Domain Controller.**](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-dc.html)

You are free to use other guides, of course. But you should know how to read and follow them and how they do apply to different distributions and skills of the reader. Most projects start their documentation with how to compile the software. However when you are using a distribution like Ubuntu that provides precompiled packages, you should install the provided packages instead, because maintaining a self compiled installation can be quite a burden, as you have to compile every update and sometimes even need to backport patches.

Also notice that Ubuntu comes with a precompiled [Samba 4 (meta)package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/samba4).